# BigQuery: 403 User Rate Limit Exceeded but error not shown in joblist

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery

Im reciveing 403 User Rate Limit Exceeded error making querys but I'm sure I'm not exceding.
In the past I've reach the rate limimt doing inserts and It was reflected in the job list as

> [errorResult] => Array
>                           (
>                               [reason] => rateLimitExceeded
>                               [message] => Exceeded rate limits: too many imports for this project
>                           )

But in this case the jobs-list doesn't reflect the query (nor error or done), and studing the job-list i haven't reach the limits or have been close to reach it (no more than 4 concurrent querys and each processing 692297 Bytes)

I've the billing active, and I've make only 2.5K querys in the las 28 days.

Edit: The user limit is set up to 500.0 requests/second/user

Edit: Error code recived

> User Rate Limit Exceeded
>
> ## User Rate Limit Exceeded
>
> ### Error 403

Edit: code that I use to make the query jobs and get results

```
function query_data($project,$dataset,$query,$jobid=null){


    $jobc = new JobConfigurationQuery();
    $query_object = new QueryRequest();
    $dataset_object = new DatasetReference();
    $dataset_object->setProjectId($project);
    $dataset_object->setDatasetId($dataset);
    $query_object->setQuery($query);
    $query_object->setDefaultDataset($dataset_object);
    $query_object->setMaxResults(16000);
    $query_object->setKind('bigquery#queryRequest');
    $query_object->setTimeoutMs(0);
    $ok = false;
    $sleep = 1;
    while(!$ok){
        try{
            $response_data = $this->bq->jobs->query($project, $query_object);
            $ok = true;
        }catch(Exception $e){ //sleep when BQ API not avaible

            sleep($sleep);
            $sleep += rand(0,60);
        }
    }
    try{
        $response = $this->bq->jobs->getQueryResults($project, $response_data['jobReference']['jobId']);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        //do nothing, se repite solo
    }

    $tries = 0;
    while(!$response['jobComplete']&&$tries<10){
        sleep(rand(5,10));
        try{
            $response = $this->bq->jobs->getQueryResults($project, $response_data['jobReference']['jobId']);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            //do nothing, se repite solo
        }
        $tries++;
    }

    $result=array();
    foreach($response['rows'] as $k => $row){
        $tmp_row=array();
        foreach($row['f'] as $field => $value){
            $tmp_row[$response['schema']['fields'][$field]['name']] = $value['v'];
        }
        $result[]=$tmp_row;
        unset($response['rows'][$k]);
    }


    return $result;

}
```

Is there any other rate limits? or it is a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: I fixed it by using only one client, it's explained in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using only one server to make the requests.

Looking what I was doing different in the night cronjobs (that never fail) the only diference was I was using only one client in one server instead of using diferent clients in 4 diferent servers.

Now I have only one script in one server that manages the same number of querys and now it never gets the User Rate Limit Exceded error.

I think there is a bug managing many clients or many active IPs at a time, althought the total number of threads never exceds 20.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error trying to import CSV files right?

It could be one of these reasons:

```
Import Requests

Rate limit: 2 imports per minute
Daily limit: 1,000 import requests per day (including failures)
Maximum number of files to import per request: 500
Maximum import size per file: 4GB2
Maximum import size per job: 100GB2
```

Comment: I get the 403 error in a query job, I paste the import error just to say that I don't get any error in the job list, also the query is not listed as done. It is really extrange because it only happen some times and I can't find the way to reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

The query() call is, in fact, limited by the 20-concurrent limit. The 500 requests / second / user limit in developer console is somewhat misleading -- this is just the number of total calls (get, list, etc) that can be made.

Are you saying that your query is failing immediately and never shows up in the job list?

Do you have the full error that is being returned?  I.e does the 403 message contain any additional information?
thanks

Comment: Hi Jordan, the project id is "minube-stats". I'm polling each 5-10 secs (rand(5,10).

Comment: We're actually in the middle of a fairly major overhaul of our quotas for load jobs, with the goal of making it easier to get data into BigQuery. Currently, for loads, we do the quota check before we create a job, so you won't get a job with an error, you'll just get a result with an error. There is a short term rate limit of 4 jobs per 2 minutes that you are likely running into (this includes failures)

Comment: Hi Jordan, I've update my question to include the code I use to make querys. I thought that the jobs of type **"bigquery#queryRequest"** doesn't have the jobs limit (only the requests/second/user limit that is set in the google console) Am I wrong? Thank you.